# How to improve substring detection as a suffix

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, string, substring

I am pretty new to C# and I am pretty sure this function can be radically improved:

```
public static Boolean SuffixExists(String strWhole, String sufx)
    {
        int iLen = sufx.Length;
        if (iLen > 0)
        {
            String s;
            s = strWhole.Substring(strWhole.Length - iLen, iLen);
            if (sufx != s) return false;
            else
                s = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am going to be calling this function from within a foreach loop. If the passed substring is present as the suffix of the passed whole string, then I will want to alter the whole string passed here by adding a prefix. I did a little testing on this code but I know it is very ugly. I'm using .Net 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Aside from the obvious System.String FCL method to do what you're trying to achieve above, why are you setting s to null?

Comment: Adding the sillyness of s = null eliminated a compile-time complaint about uninitialized variables or something like that..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

return strWhole.EndsWith( sufx );

Comment: A case where a little extra familiarity with your framework comes in very handy...